# Json4s throwing error during json extraction after jar upgradation

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am trying to upgrade the scala version from `2.11.7` to 2.11.12.

And I am also upgrading following dependencies

```
json4s-core      :: 3.5.0 -> 3.5.3
json4s-native    :: 3.5.0
jackson-databind :: 2.10.1
```

But whenever I am trying to use the "extract" method provided in the jar it throws the below exception

unknown error
org.json4s.package$MappingExcpetion : unknown Error

Comment: You will need to add more details to the question (the snipet of code with corresponding error trace). Also, please properly format your question for better understanding.

Comment: Also, it is very important to use the same version for all the `json4s` packages. So use either `3.5.0` or `3.5.3` for both of `json4s-core` and `json4s-native`. And why do you need `jackson` if you are using `json4s-native` ?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!